# Quicksorting an array of the same numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm attempting to learn the workings of the Quicksort algorithm.  I'm doing this by reading the CLR algorithms book.  I can't seem to figure out how the algorithm works for an array of the same numbers and I wasn't able to find any examples online.  For example what would the progression of the quicksort algorithm be for this:

```
{5h, 5i, 5j, 5k, 5m, 5n}
```

where the characters (h,i,j,k,m,n) are merely there to differentiate between the various 5's
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Quicksort is not inherently stable sort if that's what you're asking. Equal values might be arbitrarily reordered depending on the implementation. Some implementations are in fact stable, but most you find in the wild are probably not.

Comment: @Joren - The implementation used by the CLR book is not stable, and that is the one I am trying to get a grasp on

Comment: @James First, implement the algorithm in your programming language of choice. Then, trace it's execution. Finally, post your code and question if you still don't understand how it works.

Comment: Don't close this - I don't think this is too localized. Every semester, thousands of students study this exact same quicksort implementation(from the MIT "Intoduction to Algorithms" book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That damn book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) could have been much easier to digest had they used sensible variable names, but I guess they didn't want to diverge from the normal single letter variable convention used for all the math.

I tried to keep their function and variables names and pretty much copy the code, including the "arrays start at 1" convention they use. I mimicked the non random pivot version.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p7R99/

or just put the following in a .html file

```
<pre id="out">
</pre>

<script>
function QUICKSORT(A, p, r) {
    if (p < r) {
        var q = PARTITION(A, p, r);
        output("q=" + q + " and A=" + arr(A) + "\n");
        QUICKSORT(A, p, q - 1);
        QUICKSORT(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}

function PARTITION(A, p, r) {
    var x = A[r];
    var i = p - 1;
    for (var j = p; j < r - 1; j++) {
        if (intval(A[j]) <= intval(x)) {
            i = i + 1;
            swap(A, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(A, i + 1, r);
    return i + 1;
}

function intval(str) {
    return parseInt(str, 10);
}



function swap(A, i, j) {
    var tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = tmp;
}

function output(msg) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("out");
    ele.innerHTML += msg;
}
function arr(A) {
    return A.slice(1).join(" ");
}


var A = [undefined, "5h", "5i", "5j", "5k", "5m", "5n"];
QUICKSORT(A, 1, A.length);
</script>
```

result

```
q=1 and A= 5i 5j 5k 5m 5n 5h
q=6 and A= 5i 5j 5k 5m 5h 5n
q=4 and A= 5i 5j 5m 5k 5h 5n
q=2 and A= 5j 5i 5m 5k 5h 5n
```

Comment: what does q represent exactly?  Thanks for dissecting this.  I think it will help

Comment: `q` represents the array index of the pivot, after partition returns. It also represents a partitioning point in the array, where the stuff to the left is less than it, and the stuff to the right is greater. Also, in the case of unique elements, the value at A[q] would never move once placed into that position. So, you could say partition puts a pivot element into the correct final array position, even though the quicksort algo isn't anywhere near finished yet.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful and I have had fun playing around with the code!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few cases when quicksort could give a O (n^2) performance since (with a less careful implementation) there is a possibility that one of your partition might end up being empty.

If you know about the input before hand and they are mostly same, you might want to consider [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or a [three way quicksort](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.sg/2010/10/all-you-need-to-know-about-quicksort.html)